# which namespace class HttpClient should be used in UWP applications?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, httpclient, uwp

Hey I am developing side project for `Universal Windows Platform` that will target Windows 10 Mobile phones (mainly). In this app I often ask web service to get and post data with use of `HttpClient` class.

Now I am confused because some examples shows that you should use class HttpClient from namespace: [Windows.Web.Http](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/windows.web.http.aspx), and some from [System.Net.Http](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http(v=vs.118).aspx). Methods are different between them, but I think you can achieve same results.

My question is which `namespace` I should use while developing such applications?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.Net.Http.HttpClient vs Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient - What are the main differences?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31291008/system-net-http-httpclient-vs-windows-web-http-httpclient-what-are-the-main-di)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Windows.Web.Http` is a `WinRT API` available in all the `WinRT` programming languages supported: C#, VB, C++/CX and JavaScript. This enables the option to write the same code in the language of your choice.

`System.Net.Http` is a .NET API, and it is only available for C# and VB developers.

The new API is better capable handling new methods related to the HTTP protocol, like WebSockets, etc.

The new API doesn't have dependencies to some low-level Windows functions, like the current API does.

Your question has been answered before , please look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31291008/system-net-http-httpclient-vs-windows-web-http-httpclient-what-are-the-main-di) , I hope this would help you .

Comment: Which one of the two is "the new API"?