# System.Net.Http.HttpClient adding If-Modified-Since header

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, dotnet-httpclient, if-modified-since

I am attempting to issue an Http Get request from a windows universal app and seeing an odd behavior. (not sure if the fact that it is a universal app is related or not).

The simplified code in question is this:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.GetAsync("https://storage.googleapis.com/pictureframe/settings.json");
var s = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

In a unit test or console app that works as expected and the variable `s` contains the json content.

However in the app where I am trying to add that code (Universal Windows App targeting Windows 10 build 10240) the raw http request looks like this:

```
GET https://storage.googleapis.com/pictureframe/settings.json HTTP/1.1
Host: storage.googleapis.com
If-Modified-Since: Sun, 27 Dec 2015 18:00:08 GMT
If-None-Match: "5c43f7f07270bda3b7273f1ea1d6eaf7"
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

The `If-Modified-Since` header rightly causes google to return `304 - not modified` so I get no json file back. The thing is I am not adding that header, nor can I figure out where it is being added and how to stop it.

Is there a circumstance in which this would be expected and if so how does one control that behavior.

Comment: Are you under a proxy?

Comment: @cleiton I am not. It feels like the uwp app is improperly making use of some cache

Comment: Does it make a difference if you use `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient` instead of `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`?

Comment: @Clemens - yes, same behavior using the Windows.Web.Http client.

Comment: I am not sure what was going on here but a reboot made this go away.

Answer (score 1):

This must be a side effect of `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` being on top of `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient` on **Windows 10** with **.NET Core**. Console apps still use the regular **.NET Framework**.

Since there is no way to control the cache using `System.Net.Http.HttpClient/HttpClientHandler` and `System.Net.Http.WebRequestHandler` is not available for UWP apps, then my recommendation is you switch to `Windows.Web.Http`.

Then try:

```
var filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();

// Disable cache of responses.
filter.CacheControl.WriteBehavior = HttpCacheWriteBehavior.NoCache;

// Pass filter to HttpClient constructor.
var client = new HttpClient(filter);

var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri("http://example.com"));
var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Make sure to uninstall and reinstall your app to clean the internet cache.